# How can I force a toggle command to always off?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want a command that can hide the problems. Is there any way that I use `workbench.actions.view.problems` and make it not work as a toggle but as a switch?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `View: Close Panel` command (`workbench.action.closePanel`). Note that this will close the panel no matter which tab has focus (Problems, Output, Terminal...).